# IOS: self managed telecom

Tags: ios, swift

In android you are able [to interface with the native telecom system](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged).

> The Android framework includes the android.telecom package, which contains classes that help you build a calling app according to the telecom framework. Building your app according to the telecom framework provides the following benefits:
>
> - Your app interoperates correctly with the native telecom subsystem in the device.
> - Your app interoperates correctly with other calling apps that also adhere to the framework.
> - The framework helps your app manage audio and video routing.
> - The framework helps your app determine whether its calls have focus.

What I personally care about is like accepting and rejecting incoming calls, routing the audio streams of incoming calls, and know when they hung up.  The closest thing I have found is IOS' [Callkit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) but it doesn't seem to be as feature rich as Android's telecom library and lacks the features I need.

So far I know I am able to:

1. Reject calls (by dissallowing the call in `reportNewIncomingCall`)
2. Find out when a call has finished (by using the `callObserver`)

**I am still looking for:**

1. Accept calls
2. Stream audio to my incoming calls

Which library should I use for these two things, are both even possible in IOS?

**My use case**

I basically want the ability accept a call and then instead of immediately connecting to the user, I want to play an audio stream first, before the user gets notified.

Comment: You cannot do any of this on iOS unless you implement a VoIP app and the incoming call is to your VoIP app.  If your app is a VoIP client then it can reject its own incoming calls, but it cannot reject calls made to other apps or the cellular phone number.  The call observer is only called for calls that your VoIP app initiates or answers; it is not called for calls to other apps or the cellular phone.

Comment: I see, so basically no ios alternative for the Android API. Thank you